# Cramer-Rao inequality in model-based pricing

Tags: inequality

Given a constant vector $\mathbf{h}^* \in R^d$, define ${{\mathbf{h}}^{\delta}}={{\mathbf{h}}^{*}}+\mathbf{w}$, where $\mathbf{w}\sim N(\mathbf{0},(\delta /d)\cdot {{\mathbf{I}}_{d}}$.

Define a function $g:{\mathcal{H}^{k}}\to \mathcal{H}$ such that $\mathbf{\tilde{h}}=g(\mathbf{h}^{{\delta}_1},\mathbf{h}^{{\delta}_2},\cdots, \mathbf{h}^{{\delta}_k})$,

s.t. $E(\mathbf{\tilde{h}})={{\mathbf{h}}^{*}}$

Question: How to prove the following inequality based on Cramer-Rao bound?

$$E\left( \left\| \mathbf{\tilde{h}}-{{\mathbf{h}}^{*}} \right\|_{2}^{2} \right)\ge \frac{1}{\frac{1}{{\delta}_1}+\frac{1}{{\delta}_2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{{\delta}_k}}$$.

I cannot figure out how to derive the sum term in the right side of the inequality.

Comment: From the proof of theorem 5 in the paper "Towards Model-based Pricing for Machine Learning in a Data Marketplace"

Answer (score 2):

Sufficient statistics for this problem: $$T(\{h^{\delta_i} : i \in [k]\}) = \sum_i \frac{h^{\delta_i}}{\delta_i}$$

Assuming this is complete Sufficient statistics, By Rao Blackwood theorem, any $g(T)$ such that $E(g(T)) = h^*$ is a minimum variance unbiased estimator. i.e.,
$h_{Minimum \ Variance \ Unbiased \ Estimator} = g(T)$

Hence ,
$h_{Minimum \ Variance \ Unbiased \ Estimator} = \frac{ \sum_i \frac{h^{\delta_i}}{\delta_i}}{ \sum_i \frac{1}{\delta_i}}$.

Now variance of this estimator is the cramer Rao lower bound since this is a minimum variance unbiased estimator.

This variance is exactly as you stated in the question. So in this particular case, the cramer Rao lower bound is achieved.

So now use the equation: $$ I(h^*)= -E\left(\frac{d^2 \ln P(\{h^{\delta_i}\})}{d{h^*}^2}\right)$$

Since the ditribution is iid, we can derive component wise:
$$\ln P\left(\{h^{\delta_1},h^{\delta_2},...,h^{\delta_k}\}\right) = \text{constant} - \sum_i \frac{|h^{\delta_i}-h^*|^2}{\delta_i}$$

$$\frac{d \ln P\left(\{h^{\delta_i}\}\right)}{dh^*} = \sum_i \frac{h^{\delta_i}}{\delta_i}-\sum_i \frac{1}{\delta_i} h^*$$

$$-\frac{d^2 \ln P\left(\{h^{\delta_i}\}\right)}{d{h^*}^2} = \sum_i \frac{1}{\delta_i}$$

$$I(h^*) = -E\left(\frac{d^2 \ln P\left(\{h^{\delta_i}\}\right)}{d{h^*}^2}\right) = \sum_i \frac{1}{\delta_i} $$.

So now you have the Cramer Rao bound:
$Var(h^*) \geq \frac{1}{I(h^*)}$.

Comment: Great answer! Maybe I need to study some math courses related to the minimum variance unbiased estimator to follow your answer. Anyway, thanks.